# How do I create multiple urls.py in django app?

Tags: python, django

I want to split the django app urls into two urls with different names, `urls.py` and `reset_urls.py`. First one, `urls.py` works as expected, but the second does not. I tried the obvious approach but it seems not to be working. I want the `reset_urls.py` to be an endpoint for a password reset, but after creating, it seems not to be working.  I know django allows for renaming and having multiple `urls.py` in single app, but I'm not sure exactly how it should be done, even after checking the docs(not sure I checked the right one)

Here the source code for the urls:

**URLconf:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('blog.urls', namespace='blog')),
    path('accounts/', include('users.urls', namespace='account')),
    path('accounts/reset', include('users.reset_urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**urls.py**

*Works as expected. no issue here.*

```
from django.urls import path

from users import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

app_name = 'account'
urlpatterns = [
    path('profile', views.profile, name='profile'),
    path('register', views.register, name='register'),
    path('login', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/logout.html'), name='logout'),
]
```

**reset_urls.py**

*Does not work as expected*

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views


urlpatterns = [
    path('password_reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='users/account/password_reset.html'), 
        name='password_reset'),
    path('password_reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='users/account/password_reset_done.html'), 
        name='password_reset_done'),
    path('password_reset_confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='users/account/password_reset.html'), 
        name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('password_reset_complete/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='users/account/password_reset.html'), 
        name='password_reset_complete'),
]
```

Answer (score 3):

Create an `urls` folder with `__init__.py` in it, in app directory. Then seperate your urls as you like into several files in the urls folder.

In `__init__.py` import your urls like:

```
from .reset_urls import urlpatterns_reset
from .normal_urls import urlpatterns_normal

urlpatterns = urlpatterns_normal + urlpatterns_reset
```

Comment: Okay, but how do i include it in the main `urls.py` file? Also, `urls.py` has a namedspace set to it, concatenating it with django auth views will result to an error, as Django auth views don't use namespaces  when reversing @suayip

Comment: `__init__.py` will be your main urls.py for your app (you will import all your urls and mention your final url structure at the end), if you can't use user.urls, you can rename your folder name into something else

Comment: I have followed the exact same pattern, but I am getting reverse match error. when I execute `python manage.py shell` and run `myapp.urls.urlpatterns`, they return an empty array